# How do I get RestSharp not to add oauth_callback parameters to the Authentication header

Tags: c#, api, restsharp, oauth-1.0a

I'm trying to connect to a finicky API using RestSharp. The API uses OAuth1.0 and on the initial Request Token requires oauth_callback parameter ONLY in the query and not in the Authentication Header (I have confirmed this with Postman). 
When I construct the request this way:

```
            var Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(mc_apiKey, mc_appsecret);
            Authenticator.ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader;
            Authenticator.SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.PlainText;
            client.Authenticator = Authenticator;

            var request = new RestRequest(RequestToken, Method.POST);
            string AuthorizationCallBackURL = string.Format(LoopbackCallback);
            request.AddParameter(_oauthCallback, AuthorizationCallBackURL, ParameterType.QueryStringWithoutEncode);
```

and look at the logs on the server I see the query string in the Http call,

```
http://192.168.0.187:8080/xxxx/ws/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=http://192.168.0.187:8080/provider_emailer/callback.jsp
```

but it is also in the Authentication header:

```
    Headers:
    {Accept=[application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml], 
accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate], 
Authorization=[OAuth oauth_callback="http://192.168.0.187:8080/provider_emailer/callback.jsp",
oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXX",
oauth_nonce="cei09xm04qetk2ce",
oauth_signature="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
oauth_timestamp="1591197088",
oauth_version="1.0"], 
Content-Length=[0], Content-Type=[null], 
cookie=[JSESSIONID=C8C8DB501382F7D1E52FE436600094C0], 
host=[192.168.0.187:8080], user-agent=[RestSharp/106.11.4.0]}
```

This causes a "NotAcceptable" response. The same request done with Postman without the callback parameter in the Authentication header works.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to only get the callback in the query string?

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky. I looked at the code and we don't set the callback URL to the workflow object when you use the overload without this parameter. So, you're doing it conceptually correct.

However, we must collect all the parameters (default and request parameters) plus OAuth parameters to build the OAuth signature. We then use the parameters collection and extract all of them that have a name starting with `oauth_` or `xauth_` to the request headers (in case you use `HttpAuthorizationHeader`) and by doing so, we put your query parameter to the header.

Apparently, that's not ideal and it looks like a bug, so I can suggest opening an issue in RestSharp repository. Should not be hard to fix.